# Array get min value bigger than other value

Tags: c#, linq

I have following array:

```
float[] arr = { 0, 0.1f, 0, 0.1f, 0, 0.2f };
```

What is the most elegant way to select min value that is bigger than **0** or bigger than some other value?

I've tried using `Min()` and `Select...From...OrderBy...First()` but no luck until now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the LINQ method [`Where`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx&ei=o43tUP2OHYeW0QX95IGYBw&usg=AFQjCNFYjmbxJrWOUMGvAlxO7yuAnwouZA&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.d2k) to filter out zero values then use the LINQ method [`Min`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx&ei=rY3tUKSiNoHA0QWi_oDgCg&usg=AFQjCNEOoKZI5CSToClKVGdEbidMXiKfLg&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.d2k) to retrieve the lowest value of the resulting collection.

```
arr.Where(f => f > 0).Min();
```

Comment: How to handle the null exception in this case when arr.Where(f => f > 0) do not return any result?

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude values using `Where` and then apply a `Min`:

```
array.Where(a => a > 1 && a < 10).Min();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) filter;

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

And after use [`Min()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx) method.

> Returns the minimum value in a sequence of values.

```
arr.Where(a => a > 0).Min();
```

Here is is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/sAhNts).

Answer (score 2):

All the current answers will get exceptions if all data is less than your "some other value". So, if that's not what you want, you will get `null` in this case with this code:

```
float[] arr = { 0, 0.1f, 0, 0.1f, 0, 0.2f };
var someOtherValue = 0;

var min = arr.Where(x => x > someOtherValue)
            .Cast<float?>()
            .Min();
```

Comment: Or I suggest he could use `arr.Where(x => x > someOtherValue).DefaultIfEmpty(float.PositiveInfinity).Min()` if he wanted `∞` in the case where there's no "good" value in the array.